# Adding DateTime Chooser to TextBoxFor Field - MVC 5 / Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

I am new to bootstrap and attempting to add a `DateTime` chooser to my textbox field.

I am using a table right now for formatting so I cannot use most examples as they use `div` tags, so I am trying to stick it into `th`/`tr` tags and I am not even sure if this is possible.

I am trying to implement this `DateTime` chooser: http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

and put it in this code: (my attempt thus far)

```
 @model WebApplication2.Entities.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="width: 400px">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span style="font-size: 30px; font-style:oblique">Editing for: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</span>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

            <tr>
                <th class="col-lg-3">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-1" })
                </th>
                <th class="col-lg-9">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-lg-3">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Birthday, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-1" })
                </th>
                <th class="col-lg-9" id="datetimepicker1">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Birthday, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthday)
                    @*WITH ADD-ON TO THE ICON...*@
                    <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td class="col-lg-6">
                <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success col-lg-11">Save</button>
            </td>
            <td class="col-lg-6">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index")';return false;">Home</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            language: 'pt-BR'
        });
    });
</script>
```

The form's look

[image]

On a relevant side note, How do I properly convert the original Save

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
```

to a button, such as my attempt above

```
<button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success col-lg-11">Save</button>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to use tables instead of divs?

Anyway, if you want that your submit buttons... submit the form when they are clicked they should be inside the form they have to submit. Otherwise you have to use javascript: $form.submit();

Comment: So I should just do it all as a form then? Can I still get a similar layout and design with divs?

Comment: Sorry, I have not seen the picture you posted. The answer is: OF COURSE. And a little bit longer is NEVER use tables as a layout. Use always div+css and in the case of bootstrap is quite easy to do it quite easy and fast.

Comment: Okay! By NEVER use tables for layout is that just for forms, or information layout too? I.E. my Index uses a table layout to present all the data, is that okay?

Comment: Tables are meant to be used as a table. If you want to show data is the correct HTML element. However if you want to layout a webpage like you are doing it is not correct at all. It doesn't matter if you want to put something at the right or at the left, it is layout and it should be done with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

1. I downloaded and added the files from the datepicker here: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

   - *(one .js and one .css file)*
2. added an ID to each TextBoxFor (or any other inputs using this datepicker)
3. Add the JS script at the bottom of my View and it all worked like a charm! :)

**TextBoxFor example**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Birthday, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

**JS Script at bottom of View** (I have both classes and id's that use this)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
</script>
```